# Mailkit. After calling "ImapFolder.Rename" method the folder and all its children get unsubscribed

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I'm trying to rename the existing folder by using the ImapFolder.Rename method but after that I found the folder has become "unsubscribed" and all its children too. Is it an appropriate behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is IMAP server specific and outside of MailKit's control. You'll just have to re-subscribe after moving a folder.